# Extending the gamma function to the whole of the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I know how the gamma function is defined. $$\Gamma(x) = \int_0^\infty{t^{x-1} e^{-t}} \,dt$$   How do you extend this function to the whole of the complex plane?

Comment: Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean to extend it analytically. And the answer is, you cannot. But you can do it almost by using $$\Gamma(z) = \frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{z}$$
and repeat this until you are in the right half plane. This construction immediately shows that there will be poles in $\{0,-1,-2,\ldots\}$ and the identity theorem tells you that this is the only way to extend it. Hence it is impossible to extend it to an analytic function on $\mathbb{C}$. It will be meromorphic, though.